# Write .csv in a for loop

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, export-to-csv

I want to write csv files in a for loop. Say I have a data frame `data` with 3 rows, to make it simple, of a variable `x`. In the end, I want my output to be 200 .csv files, each one containing a row of the data. The first column of the data is the identification ("ID") of my variables.

Furthermore, my data is described as the following:

```
  data:

     ID x
 [1] a  1
 [2] b  2
 [3] c  3 

 for (i in nrow(data)){
   write.csv(data[i,2], file = paste0("Directory/", "data[i,1], ".csv"))
 }
```

I run this code and a csv file is created. However, only the last row is  created, meaning that I'm found with only one file `c.csv`.

Do you know what I am doing wrong? I thought that it would automatically create all the archives. Should I save first the results in a list and then export them?

Comment: maybe i am mis-counting, but there seems to be something off with your quotation marks. Did you copy and paste the code 1:1?

Comment: `nrow(data)` is one number, not a bunch of numbers to iterate over. You need `1:nrow(data)` or `seq(nrow(data))`. Or just use `lapply`. Also, you have an extra quote on `"data[i,1]`.

Comment: The answer by @Rafael is awesome. But I suspect it may be too complex to illustrate why your code isn't working. Take a look at the code below and compare it to your own. Note where I use the apostrophes. 

`for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
   write.csv(data[i,2], file = paste0("Directory/", data[i,1], ".csv"))
 }`

Also, general tip in R. Never call your data "data". Call it "dat" or "data1" if you need to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use a loop. You can use a `data.table` approach, which will be more efficient and faster.

```
library(data.table)

# create a column with row positions
setDT(dt)[, rowpos := .I]

# save each line of your dataset into a separate .csv file
dt[, write.csv(.SD, paste0("output_", rowpos,".csv")), 
                  by = rowpos, .SDcols=names(dt) ]
```

**Making things much faster**

```
# Now in case you're working with a large dataset and you want
# to make things much faster, you can use `fwrite {data.table}`*

dt[, fwrite(.SD, paste0("output_", rowpos ,".csv")), 
               by = rowpos, .SDcols=names(dt) ]
```

**Using a Loop**

```
# in case you still want to use a loop, this will do the work for you:

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){
                      write.csv(dt[i,], file = paste0("loop_", i, ".csv"))
                      }
```

**Extra:** Saving subsets of `dataframe` by groups instead of by rows

```
# This line of code will save a separate `.csv` file for every ID 
# and name the file according to the ID


 setDT(dt)[, fwrite(.SD, paste0("output_", ID,".csv")), 
                       by = ID, .SDcols=names(dt) ]
```

*
ps. note that `fwrite`is still in the development version of `data.table 1.9.7`. Go [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for install instructions.

Comment: Hello Rafael, thank you for your reply, but I still can't figure out how to do it. I keep in receiving the following error: "Error in `[.data.frame`(vazao_total, , write.csv(copy(.SD)[, `:=`mun,  : 
  unused argument (by = mun)" . Here, my ID or V1 would be mun. Maybe I'm not seeing something...I'll keep on trying, and let you know if I find why this is happening. Also, I've tried fwrite (after having installed {data.table} through github) but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @rebeca, I've made a minor correction to the code and now it should work. Don't forget to use `library(data.table)` and `setDT(yourdata)`