# lapply and the save function in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have created a list of objects in my work environment

```
data <- c("variable1", "variable2", "variable3")
```

i would like to save the files to different directories with the variable name as the directory...  so i did this to give me a list of file names to pass to the save function via lapply..

```
paste0(data,"/",data,".rda")


lapply(data,FUN=save,file = paste0(data,"/",data,".rda"))
```

i get the error

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object ‘X[[i]]’ not found
```

i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here..

Comment: `lapply` is used where you want a list for the return value of each iteration, and offers no advantage here.  I would suggest using `for` instead.

Comment: could you demonstrate @MatthewLundberg

Comment: side note: Here is [similar SO question about how to save a series of `.csv` files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556184/write-csv-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a list of *objects*, or a list of *names* of objects? You say you have the former, but the code you give is for the latter.

Also, if you only have one object per file, then it's better to use the `saveRDS` function (and `loadRDS` to load it).

```
lapply(data, function(x) saveRDS(get(x), paste0(x, "/", x, ".rds")))
```

If you have to use `save`:

```
lapply(data, function(x) save(list=x, file=paste0(x, "/", x, ".rds")))
```

Comment: I think he has the former, but the code doesn't work for that case.  Also, my code needs `saveRDS` as well, as it is written.

Comment: your right about having the former... i made a list of variable names, not a list of the variables.. this was one of my problems..   plus this lapply function provided gives a similar error to the ones i've gotten before ..Error in gzfile(file, mode) : invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") stop("'file' must be non-empty string") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: i would like to use lapply , but i really have to use save() not saveRDS()

Comment: @cdcaveman oops, mistake. You have to use `get` to obtain the objects themselves from the names. Also, you can still use `save` instead of `saveRDS`.

Answer (score 2):

Several things going on here.

First, you need not use `lapply` when you don't care about the return value of the function called at each iteration.  It offers nothing in this case.

Second, and more importantly, what you are doing is writing objects to files with names derived from their variable names in R.  That's an anti-pattern.

Instead, create a list of the objects, and use `for` for the work.  We need to use `saveRDS` for this (thanks Hong Ooi) as `l[[n]]` is also not the name of an object in the environment.

```
l <- list(variable1 = variable1, variable2 = variable2, variable3=variable3)
for (n in names(l)) {
    fname = paste0(n, '/', n, '.rda')
    saveRDS(file=fname, l[[n]])
}
```

It would be better to just save the entire list, but then all the data would be in one file in one directory.

As for what's actually wrong with your code:

- You pass the same value for `file` to all invocations of `save`, and you don't intend to do so.  This value is a vector, but what you want is that each iteration gets one element from this vector.
- The way `lapply` computes the value to pass to the function confuses `save`.  In particular, it does this:

`names <- as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]`

That results in something like the following, which is not the name of an object in the environment.

`c("variable1", "variable2", "variable3")[[1]]`

Comment: is it arbitrary that you use   "n"  for the iterator..  n in names(l)  what is n and l here?

Comment: `l` is computed in the line above the `for` and yes, `n` is an arbitrary name.

Comment: The library(financialInstriments) function getSymbols.FI() required the files to be in .rda and as well requires the file to be in a folder of the same name..  IE variable1/variable1.rda. So that you can simply call getSymbols.FI("variable1")  which is in turn used in other calls to buildSpread()

Comment: your for loop does actually work... but i think saveRDS() is not compatible with the library i'm using to pull my data into the work space  read error below                                                                                            Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘variable.rda’ has magic number 'X'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated